# Display Moodle lesson activities/resources in other places

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

Keeping it short, I would like to display the resources/activities somewhere else on the page. I am looking for the code where I can use in a different div that will show the resources of the current week selected. Using the weekly format of 1 week per page. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, there is a function in course renderer,
**course_section_cm_list**, check that. it will provide you the list.